# SHUTDOWN_INSTALL_UPDATES flag is not always honored by the InitiateShutdown API

Tags: c++, winapi, updates

I have a feature in my software that allows users to install updates (that were already downloaded from the Windows update server) while rebooting their computer. To initiate such operation, I'm using the following API call:

```
//Info: The process has SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege enabled

if(::InitiateShutdown(NULL, NULL, 0, SHUTDOWN_INSTALL_UPDATES | SHUTDOWN_RESTART) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    //Error occurred
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting occasional reports from users that their computers reboot but Windows refuses to install updates.

Any idea why [SHUTDOWN_INSTALL_UPDATES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376872(v=vs.85).aspx) is not always honored by the OS?

PS. Last report I received was from the user running it on `Windows Server 2012 R2`, but I also get reports from `Windows 7` systems.

Comment: Doesn't windows already have a feature that allows users to install updates (that were already downloaded from the Windows update server) while rebooting their computer? What is the error code?

Comment: @VTT: Yes, it does. Unfortunately quite often updates do more harm than good if installed right away. Thus many IT administrators are not willing to "brick" their systems (and thus incur a ton of unnecessary headache for themselves.) Most IT will never enable automatic installation of updates on the systems that they manage. Instead they prefer to do it manually (say, once a month) in a controlled environment when computers are not in use. And thus they need automation (i.e. a tool) to do that.